# How do I bypass a Custom Attribute when Integration Testing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, integration-testing

Basically, I would like to do a clean Integration Testing using net6.0. I want to invoke the endpoints of my controller which will eventually go into the database and write some data. Afterward, I will assert some aspects of the inserted data.

I can bypass the Bearer Token used by `[Authorize]` attribute but cannot bypass my custom attribute named as `[HasPermission]`

I have this custom attribute:

```
public class HasPermission : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public HasPermission(string resource, string scope) 
        : base(typeof(HasPermissionAuthorize))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { resource, scope };
    }
};

public class HasPermissionAuthorize : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string _resource;
    private readonly string _scope;
    private readonly IAuthService _authService;
    
    public HasPermissionAuthorize(string resource, string scope, IAuthService authService)
    {
        _resource = resource;
        _scope = scope;
        _authService = authService;

    }
    public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        string token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        token = token.Replace("Bearer ", "");

        bool hasPermission = await _authService.HasClaimAsync(token, "permission", _resource + "." + _scope);

        if (!hasPermission)
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
```

And this is my controller:

```
[Authorize] //<-- I can bypass this
[Route("v1/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MachinesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HasPermission("Machines", "Create")] //<-- How do I bypass this?
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] AddMachineRequest request)
    {
        //some logic
    }
}
```

In my Integration Testing

```
public class ApiWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            //I'm bypassing the [Authorize] attribute here
            //However, I do not know how to bypass [HasPermission] attribute
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes("Test")
                    .Build();

                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Test";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Test";
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Test";
                }) //TestAuthHandler is written somewhere else
                .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>("Test", options => { });
        }
    }
}
```

I'm testing my code using `IClassFixture<ApiWebApplicationFactory>`. Even though I can bypass `[Authorize]` attribute, I could NOT find an elegant way to bypass `[HasPermission]` attribute.

Comment: Register custom `IAuthService` which will return what is needed?

Comment: Thank you Guru Stron, actually, I can mock that you are right. I was just looking for a more decent way if possible. But, nobody comes up with that, I'll post that answer giving the credit to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I already was thinking about Mocking `IAuthService` but as also [Guru Stron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2501279/guru-stron) pointed out, I went for that approach. So, here is my latest update on the code that solves my problem:

```
public class ApiWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            //Added this line
            services.AddTransient<IAuthService>(_ => _authServiceMock.Object);
            //Above somewhere I also mocked it like this: 
            //_authServiceMock.Setup(c => c.HasClaimAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(true);
            
            //other stuff from my original question remains here and they are the same
        }
    }
}
```